# How resolve exceptions in Scala with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to run this [project](https://github.com/salesforce/TransmogrifAI) , I have added dependency in sbt file, My sbt file looks like:

```
name := "HelloScala"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1"
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("salesforce", "maven")
libraryDependencies += "com.salesforce.transmogrifai" %% "transmogrifai-core" % "0.3.4"
```

Then I have copied the `Helloworld` folder from their repository, but having lot of issues.

```
Information:10/09/18, 12:01 PM - Compilation completed with 88 errors and 0 warnings in 15 s 624 ms
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'package.class'.
Could not access type Vector in value org.apache.spark.ml.linalg,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'OPVector.class'.
Could not access type Vector in value org.apache.spark.ml.linalg,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'OPVector.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'OpEvaluatorBase.class'.
Could not access type Evaluator in value org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'OpEvaluatorBase.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'OpHasLabelCol.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'OpHasLabelCol.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'OpHasPredictionCol.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'OpHasPredictionCol.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'OpHasFullPredictionCol.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'OpHasFullPredictionCol.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'OpHasRawPredictionCol.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'OpHasRawPredictionCol.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'OpHasProbabilityCol.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'OpHasProbabilityCol.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'ClassificationModelSelector.class'.
Could not access type Estimator in package org.apache.spark.ml,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'ClassificationModelSelector.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'InputParams.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'InputParams.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'OpPipelineStageBase.class'.
Could not access type MLWritable in value org.apache.spark.ml.util,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'OpPipelineStageBase.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.util.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'HasLogisticRegression.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'HasLogisticRegression.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'HasRandomForestBase.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'HasRandomForestBase.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'HasDecisionTreeBase.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'HasDecisionTreeBase.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'HasNaiveBayes.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'HasNaiveBayes.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'DataReaders.class'.
Could not access type Encoder in package org.apache.spark.sql,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'DataReaders.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.sql.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'OpWorkflow.class'.
Could not access type SparkSession in package org.apache.spark.sql,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'OpWorkflow.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.sql.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'SplitterParams.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'SplitterParams.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'ModelSelectorBase.class'.
Could not access type Estimator in package org.apache.spark.ml,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'ModelSelectorBase.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'HasLinearRegression.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'HasLinearRegression.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'HasGradientBoostedTreeBase.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'HasGradientBoostedTreeBase.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'HasRandomForestBase.class'.
Could not access type Estimator in package org.apache.spark.ml,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'HasRandomForestBase.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'DataCutterParams.class'.
Could not access type Params in value org.apache.spark.ml.param,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'DataCutterParams.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.param.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'HasDecisionTreeBase.class'.
Could not access type Estimator in package org.apache.spark.ml,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'HasDecisionTreeBase.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.ml.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'FeatureBuilder.class'.
Could not access term package in package org.apache.spark.sql,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'FeatureBuilder.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.sql.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'FeatureBuilder.class'.
Could not access type DataFrame in value org.apache.spark.sql.package,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'FeatureBuilder.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.sql.package.
Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'OpWorkflowCore.class'.
Could not access type Dataset in package org.apache.spark.sql,
because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
A full rebuild may help if 'OpWorkflowCore.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.sql.
/Users/monk/Desktop/HelloScala/src/main/scala/com/salesforce/hw/OpTitanicSimple.scala
Error:(42, 8) object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
Error:(95, 26) not found: value SparkSession
    implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()
Error:(143, 8) overloaded method value setLabelCol with alternatives:
  (value: com.salesforce.op.features.FeatureLike[T])OpHasLabelCol.this.type <and>
  (value: String)OpHasLabelCol.this.type
 cannot be applied to (com.salesforce.op.features.Feature[com.salesforce.op.features.types.RealNN])
      .setLabelCol(survived)
Error:(154, 64) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[com.salesforce.hw.Passenger]
    val trainDataReader = DataReaders.Simple.csvCase[Passenger](
Error:(166, 40) could not find implicit value for parameter spark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    val fittedWorkflow = workflow.train()
Error:(174, 15) value columns is not a member of Any
    dataframe.columns.foreach(println)
/Users/monk/Desktop/HelloScala/src/main/scala/com/salesforce/hw/boston/OpBoston.scala
Error:(41, 8) object Dataset is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
Error:(41, 8) object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
Error:(56, 47) not found: type SparkSession
  def customRead(path: Option[String], spark: SparkSession): RDD[BostonHouse] = {
Error:(69, 90) not found: type Dataset
    def readFn(params: OpParams)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Either[RDD[BostonHouse], Dataset[BostonHouse]] = {
Error:(69, 50) not found: type SparkSession
    def readFn(params: OpParams)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Either[RDD[BostonHouse], Dataset[BostonHouse]] = {
Error:(77, 90) not found: type Dataset
    def readFn(params: OpParams)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Either[RDD[BostonHouse], Dataset[BostonHouse]] = {
Error:(77, 50) not found: type SparkSession
    def readFn(params: OpParams)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Either[RDD[BostonHouse], Dataset[BostonHouse]] = {
Error:(94, 6) value setGradientBoostedTreeSeed is not a member of com.salesforce.op.stages.impl.selector.HasRandomForestBase[E,MS]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value setGradientBoostedTreeSeed'?
    .setGradientBoostedTreeSeed(randomSeed)
Error:(100, 43) overloaded method value setLabelCol with alternatives:
  (value: com.salesforce.op.features.FeatureLike[T])OpHasLabelCol.this.type <and>
  (value: String)OpHasLabelCol.this.type
 cannot be applied to (com.salesforce.op.features.Feature[com.salesforce.op.features.types.RealNN])
  val evaluator = Evaluators.Regression().setLabelCol(medv).setPredictionCol(prediction)
/Users/monk/Desktop/HelloScala/src/main/scala/com/salesforce/hw/dataprep/ConditionalAggregation.scala
Error:(40, 8) object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
Error:(69, 26) not found: value SparkSession
    implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()
/Users/monk/Desktop/HelloScala/src/main/scala/com/salesforce/hw/dataprep/JoinsAndAggregates.scala
Error:(40, 8) object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
Error:(74, 26) not found: value SparkSession
    implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()
/Users/monk/Desktop/HelloScala/src/main/scala/com/salesforce/hw/iris/IrisFeatures.scala
Error:(38, 36) not found: type Iris
  val id = FeatureBuilder.Integral[Iris].extract(_.getID.toIntegral).asPredictor
Error:(39, 41) not found: type Iris
  val sepalLength = FeatureBuilder.Real[Iris].extract(_.getSepalLength.toReal).asPredictor
Error:(40, 40) not found: type Iris
  val sepalWidth = FeatureBuilder.Real[Iris].extract(_.getSepalWidth.toReal).asPredictor
Error:(41, 41) not found: type Iris
  val petalLength = FeatureBuilder.Real[Iris].extract(_.getPetalLength.toReal).asPredictor
Error:(42, 40) not found: type Iris
  val petalWidth = FeatureBuilder.Real[Iris].extract(_.getPetalWidth.toReal).asPredictor
Error:(43, 39) not found: type Iris
  val irisClass = FeatureBuilder.Text[Iris].extract(_.getClass$.toText).asResponse
/Users/monk/Desktop/HelloScala/src/main/scala/com/salesforce/hw/iris/IrisKryoRegistrator.scala
Error:(40, 47) type Iris is not a member of package com.salesforce.hw.iris
    doAvroRegistration[com.salesforce.hw.iris.Iris](kryo)
/Users/monk/Desktop/HelloScala/src/main/scala/com/salesforce/hw/iris/OpIris.scala
Error:(41, 8) object Dataset is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
Error:(41, 8) object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
Error:(56, 37) not found: type Iris
  val irisReader = new CustomReader[Iris](key = _.getID.toString){
Error:(57, 76) not found: type Iris
    def readFn(params: OpParams)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Either[RDD[Iris], Dataset[Iris]] = {
Error:(57, 83) not found: type Dataset
    def readFn(params: OpParams)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Either[RDD[Iris], Dataset[Iris]] = {
Error:(57, 50) not found: type SparkSession
    def readFn(params: OpParams)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Either[RDD[Iris], Dataset[Iris]] = {
Error:(79, 6) value setInput is not a member of com.salesforce.op.stages.impl.selector.HasDecisionTreeBase[E,MS]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value setInput'?
    .setInput(labels, features).getOutput()
Error:(87, 53) type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: com.salesforce.op.features.FeatureLike[_ <: com.salesforce.op.features.types.FeatureType]
  val workflow = new OpWorkflow().setResultFeatures(pred, raw, prob, labels)
Error:(87, 59) type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: com.salesforce.op.features.FeatureLike[_ <: com.salesforce.op.features.types.FeatureType]
  val workflow = new OpWorkflow().setResultFeatures(pred, raw, prob, labels)
Error:(87, 64) type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: com.salesforce.op.features.FeatureLike[_ <: com.salesforce.op.features.types.FeatureType]
  val workflow = new OpWorkflow().setResultFeatures(pred, raw, prob, labels)
/Users/monk/Desktop/HelloScala/src/main/scala/com/salesforce/hw/titanic/OpTitanic.scala
Error:(54, 45) not found: type Passenger
  val simpleReader = DataReaders.Simple.csv[Passenger](
Error:(55, 5) not found: value schema
    schema = Passenger.getClassSchema.toString, key = _.getPassengerId.toString
Error:(55, 49) not found: value key
    schema = Passenger.getClassSchema.toString, key = _.getPassengerId.toString
Error:(79, 6) value setModelsToTry is not a member of com.salesforce.op.stages.impl.selector.HasRandomForestBase[E,MS]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value setModelsToTry'?
    .setModelsToTry(LogisticRegression, RandomForest)
Error:(83, 53) type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: com.salesforce.op.features.FeatureLike[_ <: com.salesforce.op.features.types.FeatureType]
  val workflow = new OpWorkflow().setResultFeatures(pred, raw)
Error:(83, 59) type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: com.salesforce.op.features.FeatureLike[_ <: com.salesforce.op.features.types.FeatureType]
  val workflow = new OpWorkflow().setResultFeatures(pred, raw)
/Users/monk/Desktop/HelloScala/src/main/scala/com/salesforce/hw/titanic/TitanicFeatures.scala
Error:(41, 40) not found: type Passenger
  val pClass = FeatureBuilder.PickList[Passenger].extract(d => Option(d.getPclass).map(_.toString).toPickList).asPredictor // scalastyle:off
Error:(43, 34) not found: type Passenger
  val name = FeatureBuilder.Text[Passenger].extract(d => Option(d.getName).toText).asPredictor
Error:(45, 37) not found: type Passenger
  val sex = FeatureBuilder.PickList[Passenger].extract(d => Option(d.getSex).toPickList).asPredictor
Error:(47, 33) not found: type Passenger
  val age = FeatureBuilder.Real[Passenger].extract(d => Option(Double.unbox(d.getAge)).toReal).asPredictor
Error:(49, 39) not found: type Passenger
  val sibSp = FeatureBuilder.PickList[Passenger].extract(d => Option(d.getSibSp).map(_.toString).toPickList).asPredictor
Error:(51, 39) not found: type Passenger
  val parch = FeatureBuilder.PickList[Passenger].extract(d => Option(d.getParch).map(_.toString).toPickList).asPredictor
Error:(53, 40) not found: type Passenger
  val ticket = FeatureBuilder.PickList[Passenger].extract(d => Option(d.getTicket).toPickList).asPredictor
Error:(57, 39) not found: type Passenger
  val cabin = FeatureBuilder.PickList[Passenger].extract(d => Option(d.getCabin).toPickList).asPredictor
Error:(59, 42) not found: type Passenger
  val embarked = FeatureBuilder.PickList[Passenger].extract(d => Option(d.getEmbarked).toPickList).asPredictor
Error:(39, 40) not found: type Passenger
  val survived = FeatureBuilder.RealNN[Passenger].extract(_.getSurvived.toDouble.toRealNN).asResponse
Error:(55, 34) not found: type Passenger
  val fare = FeatureBuilder.Real[Passenger].extract(d => Option(Double.unbox(d.getFare)).toReal).asPredictor
/Users/monk/Desktop/HelloScala/src/main/scala/com/salesforce/hw/titanic/OpTitanicMini.scala
Error:(40, 8) object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
Error:(66, 26) not found: value SparkSession
    implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(new SparkConf()).getOrCreate()
Error:(75, 34) value transmogrify is not a member of Any
    val featureVector = features.transmogrify()
Error:(78, 36) value sanityCheck is not a member of Any
    val checkedFeatures = survived.sanityCheck(featureVector, checkSample = 1.0, removeBadFeatures = true)
Error:(78, 63) not found: value checkSample
    val checkedFeatures = survived.sanityCheck(featureVector, checkSample = 1.0, removeBadFeatures = true)
Error:(78, 82) not found: value removeBadFeatures
    val checkedFeatures = survived.sanityCheck(featureVector, checkSample = 1.0, removeBadFeatures = true)
Error:(81, 73) too many arguments for method setInput: (features: (com.salesforce.op.features.FeatureLike[com.salesforce.op.features.types.RealNN], com.salesforce.op.features.FeatureLike[com.salesforce.op.features.types.OPVector]))com.salesforce.op.stages.impl.classification.BinaryClassificationModelSelector
    val (pred, raw, prob) = BinaryClassificationModelSelector().setInput(survived, checkedFeatures).getOutput()
/Users/monk/Desktop/HelloScala/src/main/scala/com/salesforce/hw/titanic/TitanicKryoRegistrator.scala
Error:(41, 50) type Passenger is not a member of package com.salesforce.hw.titanic
    doAvroRegistration[com.salesforce.hw.titanic.Passenger](kryo)
```

I tried to search about those issues and found it can be version issue, But I am not getting which version should I use, if there is version issue. 
But if I am trying to run it from command line, it's working:

```
cd helloworld
./gradlew compileTestScala installDist
./gradlew -q sparkSubmit -Dmain=com.salesforce.hw.OpTitanicSimple -Dargs="\
`pwd`/src/main/resources/TitanicDataset/TitanicPassengersTrainData.csv"
```

It's not working from IntelliJ , How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `build.sbt` two dependency are missing: `spark-mllib` and `spark-sql`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.1",
  "com.salesforce.transmogrifai" %% "transmogrifai-core" % "0.3.4"
)
```

This will remove the first block of errors.

Comment: You should use "provided". 
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.1" % "provided",
  "com.salesforce.transmogrifai" %% "transmogrifai-core" % "0.3.4"
)

Comment: @Luca , two question :
How did you find that i have to add those dependencies.
First block of errors are gone, Now i am facing https://notepad.pw/y37gplk1

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul cos' of `Could not access type *** in value org.apache.spark.ml.linalg` is in package "spark-mllib" and `Could not access type *** in package org.apache.spark.sql` is in package "spark-sql"

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul for the remaining errors. The problem is that `Passenger` is a data structure defined in avro. You need to integrate your sbt code with a plugin that generate the `Passenger` class from the avro definition.